# redirect using middleware : redirected you too many times

Tags: redirect, next.js, middleware

I want to redirect to the login page using "Middleware", but it gives the following message:
This page isn’t workinglocalhost redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I expect it working and redirect to login page but It has fallen in the loop.

This is my middleware.ts file:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const token =!!request.cookies.get('token')? true:false ;
    console.log(token);

       if (!token) {
         return (
            NextResponse.redirect(new URL( `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL}auth/login`))
         )} 
}
```